# In knockout Change Paging when Data is changed

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-3.4

In knockout I wish to change/ refresh Paging when data is changed.
For example: I have a data set of 100[5 Records per Page]  and I am on Page 10. Now  with some more search Data is changed from 100 to 5 and I am on Page 10, but when data is changed I want paging to be on First page. i.e Paging to be refreshed.

Here is my [Fiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/975ncawv/281/)

```
MyVM.prototype.loadData = function(rawData) {
  this.items(rawData.map(RowModel.fromRawDataPoint));
};
ko.applyBindings(new MyVM(myData));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things need to be changed inside the `loadData` function.

1. The `all` observableArray needs to be updated with the new values of `items`, since it gets the values in a similar fashion in line 65.
2. `pageNumber` needs to be reset to 0, since `paginated` and `all` are listening to it through the computed function. (And the table is displaying the values of `paginated`).

It would look like this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/975ncawv/283/).

Answer (score 2):

> but when data is changed

```
this.items.subscribe( /* ... */ )
```

> I want paging to be on First page

```
this.pageNumber(0)
```

Put together:

```
this.items.subscribe(function() {
  this.pageNumber(0);
}, this);
```

I don't see any logic concerning the search data, but I'd expect something along the lines of:

```
this.filteredItems = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  return this.items().filter(/* ... */);
}, this);
```

Once implemented, you can change the subscribe to `items` to be on `filteredItems` to make sure you reset *both* when the data *source* changes as well as when the *search query* changes.